# Getting Null Pointer in PreparedStatement.close()

Tags: java

im trying to insert values from textfield to mySql using jdbc but my problem is im having a null pointer error when closing my prepared statement. here's my code

```
 private Connection con;
 private Statement stm;
 private ResultSet rs;
 private PreparedStatement ps ;



public void dbConnect(){
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        this.con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbTestDrive"
                + "", "root", "password");

    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException ex){}
    catch(SQLException ex){}
}

 public boolean insert(Member member)throws SQLException{
    this.dbConnect();
    boolean success = false;
    String query = "INSERT INTO try VALUES(?, ?)";
            try {
        this.ps = this.con.prepareStatement(query);
        this.ps.setString(1, member.getMemberId());
        this.ps.setString(2, member.getFirstName());


       int rows = this.ps.executeUpdate();
        if(rows>0){
            success = true;
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        throw ex;
    } finally{
        this.ps.close(); // this is my line: 56 (im getting null pointer here)
        this.con.close();
    }

    return success;
}
```

here's the stacktrace:

```
   Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at rtu.tomis.dao.MemberDao.insert(MemberDao.java:56)
at rtu.tomis.gui.AddMemberView.btnSaveActionPerformed(AddMemberView.java:993)
at rtu.tomis.gui.AddMemberView.access$800(AddMemberView.java:21)
at rtu.tomis.gui.AddMemberView$9.actionPerformed(AddMemberView.java:476)
```

thank u for your help

Comment: Are you sure there is no exception thrown in the catch block above the finally block? That seems to be the only case when ps could be null. Also, you can move all those connection related objects to insert method as local variables as they should be created everytime (except may be the connection object which can be maintained as member but tricky depending on how your class is going to be accessed)

Comment: You have some issues in your code. `1.` You are trying to catch and throw exception at same time for your `insert method`. `2.` Not that important but `success` is `boolean` then you can return from your blocks anytime. `3` Why are you referencing everything with `this`, you don't need to do that.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting an exception inside the `try` block, somewhere before or while this line executes:

```
this.ps = this.con.prepareStatement(query);
```

After the `catch` block rethrows the exception, the `finally` block executes. Unfortunately, because `ps` is `null`, you get another exception, which is then thrown, hiding the original exception.

You need to code more defensively, closing `ps` and `con` only if they are not `null`, and catching any exceptions that the `close()` calls might themselves raise. This will allow you to propagate any exceptions thrown by the body of the `try`.

You should also not silently ignore exceptions thrown in the `try` block of `dbConnect()`. I suspect that an exception there is the root of your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You should write your code like this :

```
finally{
  if(ps != null)
        try{
            this.ps.close(); 
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("PreparedStatement close problem");
        }
  if(con != null)
        try{
            this.con.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Database Connection close problem");
        }
}
```

This will avoid null pointer exception if any of the `con` or `ps` were not initialized due to some error.

Also you can remove `this` keyword from all your code because you don't have any local variables of your method with the same name as your class variables , so there won't be any ambiguity

Comment: Also consider wrapping the close() in a try/catch block and log any errors that may occur.

Comment: i try your code @Abu but i got anothe null pointer at line 41:                   this.ps = this.con.prepareStatement(query);

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for null in the finally clause

```
finally{
  if(ps != null)
        this.ps.close();
   //
}
```

but the underlying problem may be when you open your connection, after it fails **it will not initialize** your prepared statement:

```
this.ps = this.con.prepareStatement(query);
```

In other words, before calling `prepareStatement` make sure `con` is not null. You should change your method `dbConnect` and print the exceptions, this will help you take care of the cause of the problem.

```
 try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        this.con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbTestDrive"
                + "", "root", "password");

    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException ex){
     ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(SQLException ex){
     ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: yes @Ulises 'this.ps = this.con.prepareStatement(query);' i got null pointer in this line after trap null in finally()

Comment: @rheighy Yes, what I'm saying is that before calling prepareStatement, you need to check con is not null. I'll update my answer in a sec

Comment: how will i know if con is not null? i tried to debug my program and con and ps give me a null value

Comment: @rheighy print the stack as I mentioned before so you see previous exceptions. Also add a check for null for con: `if(con!=null) this.ps = this.con.prepareStatement(query);`

Comment: my con is null. how can i fix that?

Comment: hi @ulises i found my error it's my jar file of mysql connector =) thanks to all of u, =)

Answer (score 0):

I do think that there was an exception thrown in your dbConnect() method that's why the jvm reads directly to the finally before reading the instantiation of your prepared statement.

Comment: im now having null pointer in this line:                        this.ps = this.con.prepareStatement(query);

Comment: i'm thinking that maybe your insert statement (variable query) is wrong. if you're columns is greater than two you need to specify the columns that your going to populate. e.g. "insert into try ([column name], [column name]) values (?, ?);

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting Prepared Statement object in your insert method and invoking anything on null give you Null Pointer Exception.